# Eloquent Many to Many attach() is passing a null model ID

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am developing an application using Laravel and Eloquent ORM, it uses a database filled with event information.

I have successfully implemented `attach()` in the relevant controllers for both my user and role models.

My Event model can have many Links. A Link can have Many events.
My problem is that the `attach()` is not supplying the ID of the object it is being called on, instead it supplies null and I receive the following error message:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
>
> 1048 Column 'link_id' 
>   cannot be null (SQL: insert into 'event_link' ('created_at', 'event_id', 
>   'link_id', 'updated_at') values (2018-06-09 11:27:15, 2, , 2018-06-09 11:27:15))

I've triple checked my models and database structure.

I can't even imagine how this error could occur since the id lacking in the SQL query is the `id` of the object that the `attach()` method is actually being called on. If I use `sync($eventID, false)` instead of `attach()`, the result is the same.

Event table:

[image: Event table]

Link table:

[image: Link table]

Event_Link table:

[image: Event_Link table]

The following is the problematic method in the controller responsible for storing the record and creating an entry in the `event_link` weak entity.

The `$link` object is created successfully if the `attach()` line is commented out, a JSON representation of a link is returned which confirms this (but it lacks the '`id`' field).

```
    public function store(StoreLink $request) {
      $link = Link::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'url' => $request->url,
      ]);

      if ($request['eventId']) {
        // $request->eventId is passed successfully, $link id is not passed.
        $link->events()->attach($request->eventId);
      }
      return response()->json($link, 201);
    }
```

Link Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Link extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'links';
  public $incrementing = false;
  public $timestamps = true;
  protected $primaryKey = "id";
  protected $fillable = ['title', 'url'];

  public function events()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event')->withTimestamps();
  }
}
```

Event Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Event extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'events';
  public $incrementing = false;
  public $timestamps = true;
  protected $primaryKey = "id";
  protected $fillable = ['description', 'date', 'image', 'category_id'];

  public function category()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Event', 'category_id');
  }

  public function links()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Link', 'event_link')->withTimestamps();
  }

  public function history()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_history');
  }

  public function favourites()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_favourites');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `public $incrementing = false;`: Remove the line from both your models.

Your `id` columns are defined as `AUTO_INCREMENT`, so `$incrementing` has to be `true`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! That was the problem. I was confused and thought `$incrementing = false` had to be set to prevent Laravel from automatically managing/inserting the primary key id.

Comment: You can also remove `protected $table = '...';` and `protected $primaryKey = "id";`. Your values are already the default values.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll do that now!